# Django-rest-framework serializer: Create an object with foreign objects at the same time

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Background: I have an Article model storing some articles and each article can have multiple images. I need to design an api to create an article and the corresponding images if necessary. But I have no ideas of how to make the images can be also created at the same time.

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class ArticleImage(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path, blank=True, null=True)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
```

serializers.py

```
class ArticleImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ArticleImage

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #images = ???
    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

api.py

```
class ArticleView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            serializer = ArticleSerializer(request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response({'success': True})
            else:
                return Response({'success': False})
        except:
            return Response({'success': False})
```

Request JSON

```
{  
   "title":"Sample Title",
   "content":"Sample Content",
   "images":[  
      "paul.jpg",
      "ada.jpg"
   ]
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is the jpg image data included in json/post somehow? Otherwise where will the images come from?

Comment: Yes, the image is included. The request json is a sample of the data structure for anyone's reference and actually when calling the api, the Content-Type should be "multipart/form-data". Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Anyone help for this question? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using DRF v3, you can find the answer to your question under the **"Writable nested representations"** section of the official docs on **"Serializers"**.

Let me know if you need more help.